# Circular Progress bar for step counter/fitness application

Tags: java, android, kotlin, progress-bar, customization

[image]

Hello everyone. Please help me! How can I make a custom view like this. I need this view for a fitness application and after a lot of search results, I can't find exact solution for this. If you know a library for views like this, please let me know. Or If you know how can I make this view by hand in kotlin or java for android, please share with me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use circular progress bar. you can use this library from git. 
[CircularProgressBar](https://github.com/lopspower/CircularProgressBar)

Implementation is there.

Comment: thanks a lot for this library

Comment: how can I add a circle on tip of indicator? Do you know how to handle this issue?

Comment: Please accept the answer if it works for you. If you want to add a circle on tip then it would be more customisation. You need to fork the library and make your changes if allowed.